# Creating nested dictionaries using for and if loops

Tags: python, linux, dictionary

I am working on creating nested dictionaries. Can someone please help?

```
for key,values in hostwise.iteritems():
    values.sort(key=lambda x: x.execution_time)
    for plugin in values:
        plugin_wise = {}
        if plugin.name not in plugin_wise.keys():
            plugin_wise[plugin.name] = {}
            if plugin.status == 'Submitplugin':
                plugin_wise[plugin.name]['Submitplugin'] = plugin.execution_time
            elif plugin.status == 'Pluginsucceeded':
                plugin_wise[plugin.name]['Pluginsucceeded'] = plugin.execution_time
        else:
            if plugin.status == 'Submitplugin':
                plugin_wise.update({plugin.name: {'Submitplugin': plugin.execution_time}})
                #plugin_wise[plugin.name]['Submitplugin'] = plugin.execution_time
            elif plugin.status == 'Pluginsucceeded':
                plugin_wise.update({plugin.name: {'Pluginsucceeded': plugin.execution_time}})
                #plugin_wise[plugin.name]['Pluginsucceeded'] = plugin.execution_time
```

```
{‘UpgradeOptional’: {‘Pluginsucceeded’: ‘2020-06-06T12:00:09’}}
{‘UpgradeOptional’: {‘Submitplugin’: ‘2020-06-06T12:00:03’}}
```

For example. the above output is not what I am expecting...I want the way below. Any ideas please?

```
{‘UpgradeOptional’: 
    {‘Pluginsucceeded’: ‘2020-06-06T12:00:09’,‘Submitplugin’: ‘2020-06-06T12:00:03’}}
```

Comment: what is the problem? Does this code throw any type of error? or does it produce the wrong output?

Comment: It produces the output which I am not expecting.. Basically I want this way..  one key and two values(each a seperate dictionary itself) ‘{UpgradeOptional’: 
    {‘Pluginsucceeded’: ‘2020-06-06T12:00:09’,‘Submitplugin’: ‘2020-06-06T12:00:03’}}

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

plugin_wise[plugin.name].update({'Submitplugin': plugin.execution_time})

plugin_wise[plugin.name].update({'Pluginsucceeded': plugin.execution_time})

Answer (score -1):

I think the part that you have commented out should work.

Comment: Actually I tried that already and it didn't work, so tried update method and see if it works.. but that didnt work either as well